# I don't have previous signature certificate and I want to upload a latest version of my application in play store

Tags: android, upload, certificate, upgrade, signature

I don't have previous signature certificate and I want to upload a latest version of my application in play store.

The previous app was developed my another developer. Now I want to upgrade and sign it by myself.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please outline what you have tried and be more specific about what is not working. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application already released has **Google Play App Signing** enabled then it's possible to "Generate a new private key and certificate" and then contact Google support team.
On the other side if **Google Play App Signing** is not enabled you can't upgrade the existing app ...

look at this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change details of already issued certificate nor issue new certificate as drop-in replacement for your old certificate. So basically if your application is already released you either stick with the cert you used or you need to drop the certificate which in this case means you need to release new application (not the update).